# Formatting logic app expression for DateTime

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I  am  generating a file  for export with the file name utcnow in the logic app expression which returns a value like this

utcNow()-  "2020-06-01T15:41:15.5103915Z"
I want to convert  it like "20200601154151" that means I need  to remove  some characters like" -","T"  and millisecondsfollwed by Z,
I tried few combination of string format and I am not getting it right hoping you  guys  to help me.
Thanks,

Comment: Please check the expect result you want, in your question you want `20200601154151`, this leads to confuse. Do you want `20200601154115` ? or `2020060115411551` ?

Comment: hi and welcome, look in to using regex to replace values in string
https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-use-match-test-replace-regular-expressions-in-microsoft-flow-and-azure-logic-apps-and-84e6cb848e86

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many options for [custom date formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Here is a simple guide:

- yyyy = Year (2020)
- MM = Month (06)
- dd = Day (01)
- HH = Hour (15)
- mm = Minute (41)
- ss = Second (15)

Construct a format string (ex: yyyyMMddHHmmss) based on your requirements and pass it to *formatDateTime*:

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

The resulting value will be '20200601154115'. There are many additional options at the link above.